# Inject a button close to input box

Tags: javascript, button, text, inputbox

```
<input type="text"id="text111" name="text111">
```

I have this line and trying to inject a button at the right side of the textbox... Please advice how can I do it in JS?

It's an extension for chrome
I'm going to find every instance of the ID and inject it... but how?

Comment: it would be easiest with HTML  && CSS to be honest

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), details are commented in Snippet

**SNIPPET**

```js
// Reference the textbox
var in111 = document.getElementById('text111');

/* use insertAdjecentHTML() method 
|| The first parameter is the position of insertion
|| The second parameter is the text that will be rendered into
|| HTML.
*/
in111.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<button id="btn">Button</button>');
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text111" name="text111">
```